# Check if ID exist table

Tags: mysql

I'm quite new to MYSQL and want to make it return each whether exist or not, however the result shown is not what I expected. I ran this query:-

```
SELECT product_id,code, 
    IF( EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM product WHERE `product_id` IN ('001','002') ), 1, 0) AS exist 
FROM product 
WHERE `product_id` IN ('001','002');
```

**Table:-**

```
product_id | code 

001 | Dark
```

**My expected result:-**

```
product_id | code | exist

001 | Dark | 1

002 |      | 0
```

**The result:-**

```
product_id | code | exist

001 | Dark | 1
```

Any idea how to produce like what my expected result?

Comment: Why don't you make that ID as `unique` so definitely it will not be repeatedly.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL just gives you the right result, there is no record with `id = '002'` so it won't be included in the result.

Leave the logic deal by your program but not MySQL.

Comment: Is there any possible way to do it via MYSQL?

Comment: @MuthaFury You'd better understand how database works. You are filtering results, but not expanding results. If you want to show the result you expected, you have to prepare a dummy result set which has the id you specified in the condition.

Answer (score 0):

If the values of `product_id` we want to return in the resultset are not in the `product` table (e.g. '002'), we need to reference a rowsource that does include the value.

One option is to use an inline view. As an example:

```
  SELECT i.product_id
       , p.code
       , IF(p.product_id IS NULL,0,1) AS `exist` 
    FROM ( 
           SELECT '001' AS product_id
           UNION ALL SELECT '002'
           UNION ALL SELECT '003'
         ) i
    LEFT
    JOIN product p
      ON p.product_id = i.product_id
   ORDER BY i.product_id
```

We don't have to use an inline view like. For example, if we have a table or temporary table that includes rows with the values we want to return:

```
  SELECT i.product_id
       , p.code
       , IF(p.product_id IS NULL,0,1) AS `exist` 
    FROM all_possible_product_id i
    LEFT
    JOIN product p
      ON p.product_id = i.product_id
   WHERE i.product_id IN ('001','002')
   ORDER BY i.product_id
```